# PDF signing PKCS11_get_private_key return NULL

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, pkcs#11

I tried to signing pdf file with e-token in linux mint.

this is the cuestion:

When i run:

`openssl engine pkcs11 -t -c`

i got:

```
(pkcs11) pkcs11 engine
     [RSA]
        [ available ]
```

I think this is ok? in other cuestion I saw

```
[RSA, rsaEncryption, id-ecPublicKey].
```

I looking for identify correctly name and type of object that contain the private key.

in

```
pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so --login -O
```

i got

```
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Logging in to "Mi dispositivo".
Please enter User PIN: 
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
label:
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
 label: 
Private Key Object; RSA
label: 
ID:         ee0318bc9438a2be
Usage:      decrypt, sign, unwrap
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
label:      le-8ee1d222-1107-4c62-b6bf-655d5408b49a
 ID:         ee0318bc9438a2be
```

so....

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -keyform ENGINE -engine pkcs11 -inkey "pkcs11:id=ee0318bc9438a2be;type=private;pin-value=password" -in prueba.pdf -out prueba_firmado.pdf
```

i got

```
engine "pkcs11" set.
No private keys found.
PKCS11_get_private_key returned NULL
cannot load Private Key from engine
140619720004032:error:80067065:pkcs11 engine:ctx_load_privkey:object not found:eng_back.c:876:
140619720004032:error:26096080:engine routines:ENGINE_load_private_key:failed loading private key:../crypto/engine/eng_pkey.c:78:
unable to load Private Key
pkeyutl: Error initializing context
```

I tried to read private key with URI of token.... and with "slot_id" method, both give me same results.

why pkcs11 engine say "no object found"??

thanks in advice for take your time to read my problem!.

Comment: when I tried to

"p11tool --list-privkeys --login pkcs11:model=p11-kit-trust;manufacturer=PKCS%2311%20Kit;serial=1;token=System%20Trust"    

i got:
Error in crt_list_import (1): PKCS #11 user error

Comment: Are you looking to sign pdf locally on server and token also connected to same server? or to client browser? Are you using any pdf component to achieve this ?

Comment: thanks for you reply, but i achive this with other method. I use jsignpdf command line option and apache server. put token in server and any client can sign files.

Comment: Great! I one needs to sign from token connected to client on Browser, one can use Browser Extension. Signer.Digital Chrome Extension is one such free extension available.

Comment: hi @sabestian, I am trying jsingpdf with aws cloudhsm and am getting the error as : "No private key was found.". Any pointers will be helpful here, thanks!

Comment: @rcde0 sorry, but i dont have any clue how to work with AWS. jsignpdf has his own community to get help. visit google groups and find "jsignpdf" good luck!

Comment: Thanks @SebastianP. I have tried the gg earlier, have not yet heard back. And the good news is that we have figured out the way. Cheers!